# Convert puppet manifest config to hiera

Tags: ruby, puppet, yaml, pacemaker, corosync

I installed corosync-pacemaker cluster via puppet. Now I would to like keep my data into hiera file. How should I convert cs_primitive section into yaml file?

```
cs_primitive { 'nfsshare_fs':
  primitive_class => 'ocf',
  primitive_type  => 'Filesystem',
  provided_by     => 'heartbeat',
  parameters      => { 'device' => '/dev/disk/lvname', 'directory' => '/share', 'fstype' => 'ext4' },
}->
```

I tried the below code but it didn't work.

```
corosync::cs_primitive:
  'nfsshare_fs':
    primitive_class: 'ocf'
    primitive_type: 'Filesystem'
    provided_by: 'heartbeat'
    parameters:
      device: '/dev/disk/by-id/lvname'
      directory: '/share'
      fstype: 'ext4'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Classes can have parameters provided by hiera, but not resources.

You would need to create a custom class in your manifest that will take parameters from hiera. For example (untested):

```
class corosync_resources (
   Hash $primitives = {},
) {
    $primitives.each |$key, $value| {
        cs_primitive { $key:
            * => $value,
        }
    }
}
```

Then in hiera

```
corosync_resources::primitives:
  'nfsshare_fs':
    primitive_class: 'ocf'
```